# rightJoin not working on laravel

Tags: php, laravel

This is my profileController

public function requests() {
        $uid = Auth::user()->id;

```
    $FriendRequests = DB::table('friendships')
                    ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'friendships.requester')
                    ->where('status', '=', Null)
                    ->where('friendships.user_requested', '=', $uid)->get();


    return view('profile.requests', compact('FriendRequests'));
}
```

This is the view file

```
@foreach($FriendRequests as $uList)
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                   <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                       <a href="#"> <img src="{{url('/')}}/public/img/{{$uList->pic}}" class="userpic" /> </a>
                        <a href="{{url('/profile')}}/{{$uList->slug }}"><span style="text-align:left;font-size:25px;margin-left:10px;" >{{ucwords($uList->name)}}</span></a>
                        @if (session()->has('msg'))
                            <p style="float:right;">{{session()->get('msg')}}</p>
                        @else
                        <span style="text-align:center;float:right;color:white;"><a href="{{url('/accept/')}}/{{$uList->id}}" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-bottom:10px;">Accept</a>&nbsp;<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-bottom:10px;">Decline</a></span>
                        @endif

                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @endforeach
```

**Why the databse is not showing the rows with null in status column ,its showing all of the rows avaialable.**

Comment: You wrote "rightJoin" in the title and "leftJoin" in the question. Which one is it?

Comment: i tested by changing the rightJoin to leftJoin .. Anyway thanks for your response . It is solved

Answer (score 0):

Your Query should look like this

```
$FriendRequests = DB::table('friendships')
                    ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'friendships.requester')
                    ->whereNull('status')
                    ->where('friendships.user_requested', '=', $uid)->get();    

    return view('profile.requests', compact('FriendRequests'));
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the answer , I found out the problem in the friend request accept codes . It was an issue in assigned column where the friend request status is being updated . Thanks for your response .